# Multiple Chains With Using Chai Expect To Equal

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to get rid of the var res if that is possible.

I was expecting to use

```
expect(booking.customers[0]).to.equal('CUST01').and.expect(booking.customers[0]).to.equal('CUST01')
```

but that doesn't work.

Here is what works, but I'd like to condense where possible.

```
describe('#create', function() {

  it('should be able to create a booking with customer and provider', function(done) {
    var mock_customers = ['CUST01'];
    var mock_providers = ['PROV01'];

    bookings.create(mock_customers, mock_providers, function(err, booking) {
      var res = booking.customers[0] == 'CUST01' && booking.providers[0] == "PROV01";
      expect(res).to.equal(true); 
      done();
    });
  });

});
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [API](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_language-chains), it looks like you can't use 'and' to chain multiple 'expect'. You can only use it chain tests for the original value, e.g.

```
expect({ foo: 'baz' }).to.have.property('foo').and.not.equal('bar');
```

What you could do is split the test into two lines

```
expect(booking.customers[0]).to.equal('CUST01');
expect(booking.providers[0]).to.equal('PROV01');
```

or skip defining 'res' and test it directly

```
expect(booking.customers[0] == 'CUST01' && booking.providers[0] == "PROV01").to.equal(true);
```